# References on De Broglie-Bohm pilot wave theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, quantum-interpretations, wave-particle-duality

Are there any good books related to the not much popular [De Broglie-Bohm pilot wave theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory) and its application in [hydrodynamics](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=hydrodynamics&as_epq=pilot+wave), [walking droplets](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=hydrodynamics+walking+droplets&as_epq=pilot+wave&gws_rd=ssl) concepts?

Comment: I dealt for a long time with the de Broglie-Bohm theory. But an application in walking droplets I didn't see. bout application in hydrodynamics I think that I can help. But you'll have to wait, because it is about an article that I write.

Comment: Sure. Please do give me the  details whenever you are done with your article.Thanks.

Comment: With pleasure. But, leave some email, or some way to find you when I complete my article.

Answer (score 1):

I know these aren't necessarily great references, but I recently read these two interesting  articles about it:

- http://www.wired.com/2014/06/the-new-quantum-reality/
- http://www.kpopstarz.com/articles/111389/20140913/fluid-dynamics-quantum-mechanics.htm

Comment: The first link is very interesting as it shows the mathematics of the classical Bohm pilot wave as an analogue in fluids.  One should keep in mind though that the plane wave, which is a simple solution for fluids is also a simple solution for quantum mechanics but the interpretation is probabilistic, not classical. All these "past waves" go against Lorenz transformations in the simplistic transportation to quantum mechanics. I could only see this working in a General relativity frame, where space is the fluid which certainly is not Bohm's model.

Comment: What is space in the Bohm model? Or rather, what is the wave? I thought the pilot wave was a wave of space-time. How do the "past waves" go against the Lorenz transformations?

Comment: The past electromagnetic impulses would have to come faster than light to impact  the electromagnetic potentials at the present, for a photon for example . Bohm seems to postulate a special function , not a space deformation although in the wiki article extensions are described http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory#Curved_space.

Comment: @BT I haven't followed your links, but the pilot wave of dBB theory is not a wave of spacetime or even a wave in spacetime.  It is a function of configuration space, just like the Schrödinger equation.

Comment: I see. I'm new to the concept of configuration space. Is it related to spacetime in some way? This page implies that each particle has its own set of dimensions in configuration space: http://www.mtnmath.com/whatrh/node74.html

Comment: @BT For two particles you have a 6d point that tells you where both particles are. For three particles you have a 9d point that tells you the x,y,z of all three particles. For n particles, you have a 3n dimensional space, and that's where the wave is waving.  It's not a wave in spacetime. All nonrelativistic quantum theories do that, not just pilot wave theories. Only Quantum Field Theory has waves in spacetime (and there is no known pilot wave theory for QFT)