# Regarding Pilot Wave Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, resource-recommendations, quantum-interpretations, bohmian-mechanics

Not as popular as the Copenhagen interpretation perhaps, but I'm truly intrigues to know the intricacies of the de Broglie-Bohm Theory. However, I could find absolutely no source which could teach me the same (unlike the innumerous texts on Copenhagen Interpretation). Does anyone have any idea where it can be studied from?

Note that [References on De Broglie-Bohm pilot wave theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149649/references-on-de-broglie-bohm-pilot-wave-theory) is on a much narrower sub-topic and its answer is not really relevant here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [References on De Broglie-Bohm pilot wave theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149649/)

Comment: This article elegantly explains the theory with the required simplicity - https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-bohm/

Comment: @Ajinkya Naik I've seen it. I want to know the math more.

Comment: This question should not be closed based on the previous question cited; that one was a much narrower subtopic about the application of the theory.

Answer (score 0):

Bohm, D. & Hiley, B.J.; *The Undivided Universe*, Routledge, 1993 (softback 1995).

It covers the theory's mathematical equivalence with standard QM, along with many words of explanation and discussion, and includes a short account of the more speculative stuff about the universal "implicate order" which Bohm suggests the pilot wave might be enmeshed in.

I know of no major critique of it, just the usual reviews and passing judgements. Perhaps others might.

The significant lesson is that, since it is mathematically equivalent to QM, it embraces nonlocality - if only for the pilot wave and not the particle (cue Bohm's implicate order as a speculative interpretation). But its mathematical formulation is clunkier to handle than the standard one (analogous to adding vectors using polar coordinates when you could use Cartesian), so it is not used in practice.

One thing I would love to know is how it would describe more recent experiments in which the spin of an electron has apparently been sent along one path and its momentum along another, to be recombined at the end. Does the particle lose its local reality and split in two, does it hand one of those properties to the pilot wave and stick to the other path, can the theory handle either interpretation, or what?